# Dynamic column header in ASP:DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm looking for a way to dynamically set a column header in a datagrid(if there's a better option than Datagrid for this, please suggest).

Is a set of columns, and 1 of the columns is, for lack of a better term, a columngroup.

for example, it would look like this

Column1 | Column2 | ColumnGroup | Column 4

and ColumnGroup would be a number of columns, determined by the count of data from a stored procedure call.

For example, it will represent the number of region tabs at http://www.thehealthline.ca/ or http://www.eriestclairhealthline.ca/.  As you can see, these sites are similar, but have different number of region tabs.  I have to generate a table that shows specific data, one of which is related to the region tabs on the site. of which can be any number of region tabs

I realize I've rambled, I hope my problem is understandable.  Would love some help from anyone that has an idea of how to do this

also, is there a way to format the columngroup like so?

|MAIN HEADER NAME|
|1|2|3|4|5|6|

Answer (score 0):

You can get your ColumnGroups into a list from the stored procedure and then loop them adding them to data grid like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < columnGroupList.Count; i++)
{    
     if (i == 0)
     {     
        dataGrid.Columns[i].Header = 'Main Header | ' + columnGroupList[i];
     }
     else
     {
        dataGrid.Columns[i].Header = columnGroupList[i];
     }
}
```

And you can add your other headers one at a time:

```
dataGrid.Columns[0].Header = ColumnHeader1;
dataGrid.Columns[1].Header = ColumnHeader2;
.
.
.
```

Comment: thanks!  I've added another question about the header to my main question, if you have an idea about that I'd appreciate it